Inverse Fourier Transform of the bosonic response function from TDOFDFT
I want to transform the bosonic response function for the homogeneous electron  gas (HEG) from time-dependent orbital-free density functional theory (TDOFDFT) from momentum to real space using an inverse Fourier transform. I want to ask, whether my derivation & assumptions are so far correct?
\begin{equation}
\chi_{B}^{HEG}(q,\omega,\varrho)=\frac{k_{F}^{3}}{3\pi^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\omega-\frac{q^{2}}{2}+i\eta}+\frac{1}{-\omega-\frac{q^{2}}{2}-i\eta}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\chi_{B}(r,r',\omega)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi_{B}(q)]=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int dq\ \chi_{B}(q,\omega)\exp{\{iq\cdot (r-r')\}}    
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\chi_{B}(r,r',\omega)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi_{B}(q)]=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{k_{F}^{3}}{3\pi^{2}}\int dq\ \left(\frac{1}{\omega-\frac{q^{2}}{2}+i\eta}+\frac{1}{-\omega-\frac{q^{2}}{2}-i\eta}\right)\exp{\{iq\cdot (r-r')\}}=\frac{k_{F}^{3}}{3\pi^{2}}(I_{+}+I_{-})    
\end{equation}
By transforming the Integral into spherical momentum coordinates as $dq=|q|^{2} \sin{\theta}\ d|q|\ d\theta\ d\phi$, with $q\cdot q=|q|^{2}$ and integrating out the angular part
\begin{equation}
I_{\pm}(\theta,\phi)=\frac{4\pi\sin{\{|q||r-r'|\}}}{|q||r-r'|}    
\end{equation}
Thus I have
\begin{equation}
I_{\pm}(\theta,\phi,|q|)=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}|r-r'|}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|q|\ \frac{|q|\sin{\{|q||r-r'|\}}}{\pm\omega-\frac{|q|^{2}}{2}\pm i\eta}    
\end{equation}
By using Integration by parts and showing that the boundary term vanishes
\begin{equation}
I_{\pm}(\theta,\phi,|q|)=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}|r-r'|}\bigg[\frac{|q|\cos{\{|q||r-r'|\}}}{\pm\omega-\frac{|q|^{2}}{2}\pm i\eta}\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}d|q|\ \frac{\sin{\{|q||r-r'|\}}}{\pm\omega-\frac{|q|^{2}}{2}\pm i\eta}\bigg]    
\end{equation}
expressing the $\sin{\{\cdot\}}$ as complex e-functions
\begin{equation}
I_{\pm}(\theta,\phi,|q|)=\frac{-1}{4\pi^{2}|r-r'|i} \bigg[\int_{0}^{\infty}d|q|\ \frac{\exp{\{i|q||r-r'|\}}}{\pm\omega-\frac{|q|^{2}}{2}\pm i\eta}-\int_{0}^{\infty}d|q|\ \frac{\exp{\{-i|q||r-r'|\}}}{\pm\omega-\frac{|q|^{2}}{2}\pm i\eta}\bigg]    
\end{equation}
We immediately see, that $I_{\pm}$ takes the form of Propagators in Quantum Field Theory (QFT). By extending $|q|\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow z\in\mathbb{C}$ into the complex plane, and utilizing the residue theorem from complex analysis $\text{Res}(f,z_{k})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} f(z)dz$ I obtain in the end a $\text{sinc}\{\cdot\}$ function behavior
\begin{equation}
\chi_{B}(r,r',\omega)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\chi_{B}(q,\omega)]=\frac{k_{F}^{3}}{6\pi^{3}|r-r'|}\frac{\sin{\{\sqrt{2\omega+i\eta}|r-r'|\}}}{\sqrt{2\omega+i\eta}}
\end{equation}
Thank you very much in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I also condensed this question into the 7 most important equations
